# Astro component script only run once

Tags: intersection-observer, astrojs

I have an Astro component with a script for control scroll animations.
The problem is the following. When the index is loaded, the script is executed and the animation is activated without problem. But when I change the page and return to the index the code no longer runs again.
Any idea how I could fix it?

```
   const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
         if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add("move");
         }
      });
   });

   const icons = document.querySelectorAll(".service-icon");
   icons.forEach((icon) => observer.observe(icon));
```

Comment: Are you using [View Transitions](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/)? If you so you will need to re-run your script e.g. with the [after-swap](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/#astroafter-swap) event.

Comment: Thanks Alex. You're right. Now it works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

(For clarity) you can use [lifecycle events](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/#astroafter-swap) when using [View Transitions](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/view-transitions/) - this is because you need to re-run any scripts/code after navigating to another page.